# QML TextArea scroll events

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols

Is there a way to know when `TextArea` scroll has reached the top or bottom? I want to implement dynamic text loading in a chat client: when the user scrolls to the top, more text is added to the document. Something like this (pseudo-code):

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

TextArea {
      id: chat
      onScrolledToTop: text = loadMoreText() + text
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Textarea` inherits from `ScrollView` which has a `Flickable` item to control the visible area. Such an item is available as the (readonly) property `flickableItem`. Among the other properties Flickable provides the `contentY`:

> These properties hold the surface coordinate **currently at the top-left
>   corner of the Flickable**. For example, if you flick an image up 100
>   pixels, contentY will be 100.

Hence you can check this property change and, once a certain threshold is reached, update your text. Mind that you should adjust the `contentY` after setting the text, to simulate the addition. Otherwise the text shown will be exactly the one just added. A nice approach, as proposed by the OP, would be to save the original `contentHeight` and set the `contentY` to the difference between the updated `contentHeight` and the saved one - also considering the applied `threshold`.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 200

    TextArea {
        id: chat
        anchors.fill: parent
        property int threshold: 10

        text: "Current\ntext\n\\to\nmove\ndown\ndown\ndown
               \ndown\ndown\ndown\ndown\ndown\ndown\ndown"
        Component.onCompleted: cursorPosition = text.length


        flickableItem.onContentYChanged: {
            if(flickableItem.contentY <= threshold) {
                var oldHeight = flickableItem.contentHeight
                text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
                            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
                            aliqua." + text
                flickableItem.contentY = threshold + flickableItem.contentHeight - oldHeight  // leave flickable in old position
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great. I edited your code to leave flickable at the exact same position as it was before adding text (to have smooth scrolling)

Comment: Yup, nice idea. You surely improved my trivial example in a nice and smart way, thanks @beemaster! By the way, I think you don't need the `threshold` in the `contentY` recalculation.

Answer (score 0):

```
ScrollView {
        width: root.width - ((root.width/10) * 2) - (root.width/15)*2
        x:  (root.width/10) + root.width/15
        height: root.height - (root.height/5)
        clip: true

        TextArea {
            id: textArea
            clip: true
            width: root.width - ((root.width/10) * 2) - (root.width/15)*2
            height: root.height - (root.height/5)
            wrapMode: "WrapAtWordBoundaryOrAnywhere"
            placeholderText: "inter description"
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should include some explanation of your code. Code-only answers are generally frowned upon.